# video share by intent only play in my own app

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I am working on video player when i share video and open that link its play on my default player not in my app. how to open that video on my app.

Here is my code(in fragment class):

```
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                    "Hey check out my app at: "+share_video);
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: Create a Deep link Follow https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.

Comment: [refer this link i hope it will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50271178/2794507)

Comment: did you tell the system that your app is able to open videos (through manifest)?

Comment: Vladyslav Matviienko i am working on fragment

Comment: Hardik Vasani  can i add manifest file in my parent fragment class.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this:- You may use the createChooser for your intent, which will displays all the app those are able to handle your intent.

For Example:-

```
   Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                    "Hey check out my app at: "+share_video);
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent);

    // Verify the intent will resolve to at least one activity
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(chooser);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use video view:
>    for streaming a link u can do something like:

```
    String LINK = "type_here_the_link";
      VideoView mVideoView  = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
      MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
      mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
      mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
      Uri video = Uri.parse(LINK);
      mVideoView.setMediaController(mc);
      mVideoView.setVideoURI(video);
      mVideoView.start();


>or for local video u can do something like:




        VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);  

               //Creating MediaController  
  MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);  
   mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);          

                          //specify the location of media file  
                       Uri uri=Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/media/1.mp4");          

                          //Setting MediaController and URI, then starting the videoView  
                       videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);  
                       videoView.setVideoURI(uri);          
                       videoView.requestFocus();  
                       videoView.start();  



> U can visit the link for more understanding:
> https://www.javatpoint.com/playing-video-in-android-example
```